# startActivityForResult from ActivityGroup in jellybean causes restart application

Tags: android, restart, activitygroup, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an application with 4 tabs, each one has an ActivityGroup.

In one tab, at certain child activity I launch the gallery to pick up a photo:

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
getParent().**startActivityForResult**(i,Documento.SELECCIONAR_FOTO_FROM_GALLERY);

This was working fine till jelly bean, in this version when I start an activity using  startActivityForResult the application restart automatically when the onActivityResult has to be called.

I know that ActiviyGroup is deprecated since a long time ago and I should move to Fragments but, is there any way to make this work in jelly bean without migrating to Fragments?

I'm trying to fix it opening the gallery as a childActivity of the ActivityGroup:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK) ;
        i.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE) ;
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)MyActivity.this.getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("MyGalleryActivity", i);  
        dialog.cancel();
```

But i get the next exception:

10-19 16:10:48.403: E/AndroidRuntime(9237): java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.sec.android.gallery3d (with uid 10112) to be run in process jaime.mapas (with uid 10165)

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Finally I moved to Fragments, very much easier than I thought.

Comment: What do you mean by "application restart", let alone "application restart automatically"?

Comment: The application restarts, it is killed and started again (the launcher activity is shown). And LogCat say nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

> This was working fine till jelly bean, in this version when I start an activity using startActivityForResult the application restart automatically when the onActivityResult has to be called.

This is expected behavior. There is no guarantee that your app's process will remain in memory when it is not in the foreground. This is no different than if the user pressed HOME, then returned to your app some time later via the recent-tasks list.

> is there any way to make this work in jelly bean without migrating to Fragments?

Fragments will not help, as it already works as expected.

Comment: I disagree, probably I explained it bad. If I launch any activity from a childActivity of an ActivityGroup using startActivityForResult the application crashes, and it has the same behaviour if I launch an external application (gallery) or another activity of the same application. This was working perfectly in previous Android versions, but with jelly bean 4.3 kill my app.

Comment: @jimbo82: "If I launch any activity from a childActivity of an ActivityGroup using startActivityForResult the application crashes" -- you cannot embed third-party activities in your app, via an `ActivityGroup` or any other means. You can try, but usually your app will crash, because your process has no rights to the other app's data, etc. This has been the case since Android 1.0. Your app was already crashing on many devices, where the device's default activity for `MediaStore` requests did not support this embedding.

Comment: @jimbo82: Fragments will not help this either, as you cannot embed a third-party activity into a fragment.

Comment: Thank for your answers CommonsWare, but when you say "you cannot embed third-party activities in your app, via an ActivityGroup or any other means"... are you saying that you cant launch the phone photo gallery to pick up a photo for your application?